Improving the condition of a system of equations
I am trying to understand by hand how balancing a matrix increases the stability of procedures like solving a system of equations. The balance procedure that I am following is here, I also found useful the following answer, my implementation of it is as follows:
import numpy as np

def power_of_two_diagonal(n):
    """Generate a diagonal matrix with powers of two."""
    return np.diag(2 ** np.arange(1, n+1))

def perm_matrix(n):
    """Generate a permutation matrix."""
    perm = np.random.permutation(n)
    P = np.eye(n)[perm]
    return P

def balance_matrix(A):
    """Balance the matrix to reduce numerical errors."""
    n = A.shape[0]
    
    # Step 1: Compute the diagonal matrix D
    D = power_of_two_diagonal(n)
    
    # Step 2: Generate permutation matrix P
    P = perm_matrix(n)
    
    # Step 3: Compute DD = P * D
    DD = np.dot(P, D)
    
    # Step 4: Compute balanced matrix AA
    AA = np.linalg.inv(DD).dot(A).dot(DD)
    
    return AA, DD

def solve_balanced_system(A, c):
    """Solve the balanced system Ab * xb = cb and return c."""
    # Step 1: Balance the matrix A to get Ab and transformation matrix T
    Ab, T = balance_matrix(A)
    
    # Step 2: Transform the vector c to cb using T
    cb = np.dot(T, c)
    
    # Step 3: Solve the balanced system Ab * xb = cb
    xb = np.linalg.solve(Ab, cb)
    
    # Step 4: Use the inverse transformation to obtain x from xb
    x = np.linalg.solve(T, xb)
    
    return x, Ab

def solve_unbalanced_system(A, c):
    """Solve the unbalanced system A * x = c."""
    return np.linalg.solve(A, c)

def compute_residuals(A, c, x):
    """Compute the residuals."""
    return np.abs(np.dot(A, x) - c)

def compute_condition_number(A):
    """Compute the condition number of a matrix."""
    return np.linalg.cond(A)

# Example usage:
# Define your matrix A and vector c
A = np.array([[3, 2, 1],
              [1, 4, 2],
              [2, 1, 3]])
c = np.array([1, 2, 3])

# Solve the system A.x = c with balancing
x_balanced, Ab = solve_balanced_system(A, c)
print("Solution with balancing:", x_balanced)

# Solve the system A.x = c without balancing
x_unbalanced = solve_unbalanced_system(A, c)
print("Solution without balancing:", x_unbalanced)

# Example usage:
# Compute residuals
residual_balanced = compute_residuals(A, c, x_balanced)
residual_unbalanced = compute_residuals(A, c, x_unbalanced)

# Compute condition numbers
cond_number_A = compute_condition_number(A)
cond_number_A_balanced = compute_condition_number(Ab)  # Corrected here

# Print results
print("Residuals with balancing:", residual_balanced)
print("Residuals without balancing:", residual_unbalanced)
print("Condition number of A:", cond_number_A)
print("Condition number of balanced A:", cond_number_A_balanced)

What makes me think that I have made a mistake in the implementation is the following output:
Solution with balancing: [ 0.    -4.2    1.175]
Solution without balancing: [0. 0. 1.]
Residuals with balancing: [ 8.225 16.45   3.675]
Residuals without balancing: [0. 0. 0.]
Condition number of A: 3.766951069700286
Condition number of balanced A: 9.451873950783218

Because not just the condition number increase but the residual becomes unacceptably large!

If $\tilde{A}=D^{-1}AD$ is the "balanced" matrix and $Ax=c$ is the system to solve, then the equivalent equation $D^{-1}ADD^{-1}x=D^{-1}c$ suggests that first we compute $\tilde{c}=D^{-1}c$, then solve $\tilde{A}\tilde{x}=\tilde{c}$, then compute $x$ as $x=D\tilde{x}$. In other words, inversion and multiplication is swapped.

Also, how do you expect your algorithm could improve the condition number of the matrix with such a naive and random choice of $D$ and $P$? It is unlikely that the linked algorithm works like this.

Am I missunderstanding they información in the links?
